# can't load maps on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

I used the MapActivity to load the google map,but there's grey grid displayed instead of google map.
I already set the API key, which was generated from my own PC, and was written in the XML.

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/myMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below = "@+id/lngText"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey ="0QEUXb8GY3QS9cQfDiZfa2vZxtBZVpxcpcSlOCQ">
 </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

And I have add the permission and the library even the feature:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/> 
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

Code is simple.

```
MapView myMap = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.myMap);
    POS = new GeoPoint((int)40.38014 ,(int)117.00021);

    MapController myMapController = myMap.getController();
    myMapController.setCenter(POS);
    latText.setText(Integer.valueOf(POS.getLatitudeE6()).toString());
    myMapController.setZoom(9);
```

Will you please help me investigate what's reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you select a Google APIs image when you created the avd?

When you create an AVD, you have to make sure to select "Google APIs (version xx)" for the target

Answer (score 0):

first check without providing geolocation to be displayed. Let the default view be displayed through which we can check whether there is really error with the program or not.

next check the internet connection. slow internet connection may also result such problems

further in the creation of avd, be sure to select Google map api aswell and during using avd select appropriate avd with google map api

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did as you suggested, still grey tiles. The logcat said:at_android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.Datarequestdispatcher.servicerequest(DatarequestDispatcher.java:994 ). And lots of "Unexpected value from nativegetEnabledTags:0"

Comment: you delete the previous avd's you created and try with the new one.first be sure you delete those pos and try with only mapview

Comment: i install the apk in my phone, and the map can load and work well. I can't understand why the emulator can't....

Comment: yes the software is hard to exactly realize as the hardware. so there can be some error in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Create new AVD, and select Target- "Google APIs (Google Inc.)-API level xx" I had attached image[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, i did choose the google api , if not, the emulator will not be launched when run the activity.